# Add shared authentication to a Classic ASP.NET Web Forms app and a Web API app

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, openid-connect, azure-ad-msal

I am replacing a shared cookie authentication design with an Open Id Connect one.

Context: The two web apps currently use `FormsAuthentication` with a shared `AuthCookie` cookie and `machineKeys`.

Systems:

- A classic Web Forms app, FormsAuthentication, `cookie=AuthCookie`, hosts `/login.aspx`
- An integrated Web API app, FormsAuthentication, `cookie=AuthCookie`

Issue 1: Microsoft's Open Id Connect library requires OWIN. I cannot convert the classic Web Forms app to an OWIN app because OWIN requires Integrated pipeline which would break my Spring.NET library that depends on the classic pipeline.

Action 1A: Convert the Web API to OWIN and added support to Open Id Connect.

Action 1B: Move authentication from the classic site to the Web API.

Issue 2: After authentication I must be able to use both systems.

Action 2: On Open Id Connect redirection, the Web API will work with the JWT bearer token stored in an Open Id Connect cookie. The Web API will create an additional cookie (`AuthCookie`) which the classic app will use.

Issue 3: How do I keep these two cookies in sync? Users must be both logged in or logged out of the two systems. What happens if one cookie is accidently deleted but not the other?

Issue 4: The Web API isn't receives cookies from Microsoft Open Id Connect but subsequent requests to my Web API don't receive cookies and the `HttpContext.Current.User` isn't being set.

Classic Web Forms code:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="webapi/login" name="LycheeAuthCookie" slidingExpiration="true" path="/" />
</authentication>
```

Web API code:

```
Startup.cs:
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions { AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive }); //Web API should return 401 not redirect to /login. The SPA will handle that
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
                ClientId = Config.ApplicationId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = $"webapi/openIdRedirect",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = $"webapi/openIdLogout",
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive, //Web API should return 401 not redirect to /login. The SPA will handle that
});
...
private Task OnSecurityTokenValidated(SecurityTokenValidatedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context) //Called on Open Id Connect authentication success
        {
            var newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
                userId,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(claims.FindFirst("iat").Value)),
                false,
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(int.Parse(claims.FindFirst("exp").Value)),
                false,
                "roles and permissions",
                FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            var cookie = new HttpCookie("AuthCookie");
            cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            cookie.Expires = newTicket.Expiration;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you host your websites on the same domain, i.e. "https://localhost", and you share the same `.AspNet.Cookies`, then it will work!

For both websites add the OWIN middleware, set your project to IIS integrated pipeline mode, and add the following `Startup.cs` file:

Website 1 at "/" - active:

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(...MyStartup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication();
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

Website 2 at "/api" - passive:

```cs
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(...MyStartup))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions {
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType
            });
        }
    }
}
```